# Spring 6: Problem Storing Session Attributes and invalidate Session

Tags: spring, spring-session

While migrating to spring 6 and spring boot 3, we have two problems:

1. The session attributes are not stored in the database anymore
2. The session is not invalidated correctly on logoff.

In **Spring 5** we have a persistent session (`session.store-type: jdbc`). When we create a session on successful login with `getSession(true)` and store the corresponding username, it is saved to the database.

In `spring_session` we find one entry
In `spring_session_attributes` we find an entry for the stored attribute a one for the `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT`.

The request returns with a cookie and the browser uses this cookie for the next request.

When we `invalidate` the session, all content is removed from the database and the request returns an empty cookie so that the cookie is also cleared in the browser.

This behavior is absolutely correct.

In **Spring 6** however the behavior is different.

If we use `http.securityContext { ctx -> ctx.requireExplicitSave(false) }` in our configuration, the session is stored in the DB but we only see the `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT` attribute and not our username attribute.

When we `invalidate` the session, it is **not** removed from the database, the browser’s cookie is **not** cleared and the session is still valid.

If we use  `http.securityContext { ctx -> ctx.requireExplicitSave(true) }` all session attributes are stored and the persistent session is removed on logoff. However, if we have multiple requests at the same time, we see these errors in the log file:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_spring_session_attributes"
  Detail: Key (session_primary_id, attribute_name)=(bc7114b1-3149-4c7b-8c23-b1023f51a8b9, SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT) already exists.
```

These requests fail with http status 500.

We have found this documentation about changed in session handling (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration/servlet/session-management.html) but it does not apply. We do not change the security context. We just use it to set the `authentication`-Property.

We tried saving the context, but it didn't solve the problem – specially not the problem with the duplicate keys.

What are we missing?
Are there more changed to spring-session-jdbc that we’ve overlooked?